# Data source in spring applicationContext for hsqldb

Tags: java, xml, spring, hsqldb, applicationcontext

I am loading `Spring 3.2.2` in my application, within the `applicationContext.xml`:

However, I am receiving the following exception:

```
344  [main] INFO  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  - Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@120d62b: defining beans [org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,personDao,dataSource,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'driverClassName' of bean class [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]: Bean property 'driverClassName' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1429)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1134)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1117)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:922)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.testPackage.App.main(App.java:11)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'driverClassName' of bean class [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]: Bean property 'driverClassName' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:1042)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:902)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:75)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:57)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1426)
    ... 13 more
```

My `applicationContext.xml` looks like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd">
    <tx:annotation-driven />
    <context:annotation-config />

    <bean id="personDao" class="com.testPackage.PersonDaoImpl" />

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/testDB" />
        <property name="username" value="sa" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
        <property name="initialSize" value="5" />
        <property name="maxActive" value="10" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

I thought that the driver is possibly the problem, but what should be taken instead for a `HSQL-DB 2.3.2`?

I really appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` should be used differently (it's not a `DataSource`), for example:

```
<beans>
    <bean id="myEmf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="someDataSource"/>
...
    </bean>
</beans>

<bean id="someDataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/testDB" />
    <property name="username" value="sa" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
</bean>
```

but if you have an "initialSize" in there, it probably should be a pool:

```
<bean id="someDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
   <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
   <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/testDB" />
   <property name="username" value="sa" />
   <property name="password" value="" />
   <property name="initialSize" value="5" />
   <property name="maxActive" value="10" />
</bean>
```

and the following in your `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thx for your answer! Any dependecy I have to add to my pom.xml?

Comment: `<dependency>
 <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
 <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
 <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>`